# How to compare mysql database every tables and rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database, nginx

My webapp running on private VM, and I've just recovered from serious system failure on data center so the mysql service keep crashing until I decided to move to the last backup VM image. It needs two days (so in last 2 days the system is unstable) in short , Is there any way to compare every table and every rows of two Mysql databases ? (same structure ofcourse). 
I have the database backup before system failure and at the point the before I move to the last backup VM image.
fyi: 
time gap(before failure and after restore) aprox. 52 Hours.
 Ubuntu 14.04,Nginx,php, and Mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a checksum for that.
Take a look at the MySQL reference for it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

mysqldiff and mysqldbcompare in mysql-utilities may helps;

**The data_check or structure_check may take a very long time;**
install the mysql-utilities by

```
apt-get install mysql-utilities
```

or yum;

use the mysqldiff like this

```
mysqldiff --server1=<user>:<pwd>@<ip> --server2=<user>:<pwd>@<ip> --difftype=unified <dbname in server1>:<dbname in server1>
```

the result is like this
[image]

mysql.gtid_executed is different in server1 and server2, the difference is showed at bottom;

to compare the data, use mysqldbcompare;

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=<user>:<pwd>@<ip> --server2=<user>:<pwd>@<ip> --difftype=unified <dbname in server1>:<dbname in server1>
```

the result is like this
[image]